# How to set parameters for a jenkins pipline scm job

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have a particular jenkins file that i would like to use as a 'git pipeline scm' job for different environments.   So i'll have a job for dev, qa, and prod all pulling the same jenkins script.   The script has some parameters and defaults..

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    parameters{
        string(name: 'environment', defaultValue: "dev")
        string(name: 'email', defaultValue: "")
        string(name: 'service_url', defaultValue: "http://dev.xyz_service")
    }
    ....
    ....pipeline script code....
    ....
}
```

These jobs will be scheduled/time triggered (non-human/manual triggers).
While i want to create 2 jobs, one for lower environment, and one for production which can be secured....i dont want to duplicate the script.  So i thought git pipeline scm to be a good solution.
But My question is, how can i set these parameters automatically after pulling the jenkins file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

key:value pairs should be hardcoded in the parameters section.
If you want to use dynamic ones there is an option to set dynamic env vars:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'some_label'
  }  
  environment {
    EC2 = """${sh(
      returnStdout: true,
      script: 'aws ec2 describe-instances \
        --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=JENKINS_EC2_NAME_FROM_TAG"\
        --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId \
        --output text'
        ).trim()}"""
  }
```

Or set it in the stage:

```
stage('notify about start of daily scan') {
  steps {
    script {
      env.mess_start=sh returnStdout: true, script: "date +%Y-%m-%d"
      env.mess_start=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "date +%Y-%m-%d").trim()
    }
  }
}
```

As a result these envs will be available globally in the pipeline.

Comment: interesting - will look at this.  so i could create a env file for each environment and read that.   This will only affect this particular process and process it launches, not other processes on the jenkins server, right?

Comment: correct, those envs will be used only on a single job run.

Comment: So what i ended up doing is putting an env specific properties file at the root workspaces for the /uat /dev/ /prod folders and im reading that.   My script also loads a utils.groovy.  What i wasnt able to do is read the variables loaded in the job itself, from the utils library, even though i declared them as job level variables.

Comment: marking your answer though..as it was close enough.  I am mostly concerned about making sure that i dont have these variables scoped globally for all runs, as there will be some parrallel jobs with different values for same variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Parameterized Scheduler](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/) plugin.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    parameters{
        string(name: 'environment', defaultValue: "dev")
        string(name: 'email', defaultValue: "")
        string(name: 'service_url', defaultValue: "http://dev.xyz_service")
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron('''
            H 1 * * * %environment=dev
            H 2 * * * %environment=qa
        ''')
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: in the lower environment, i may not want it to be scheduled.  is there an option to set those variables using a ''git pipeline scm' job?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "git pipeline scm" job. A declarative pipeline job that is stored in some scm? And what do you want the source of the values to be? Your options so far: 1) defaults hardcoded in the pipeline, 2) values set by the parameterized cron trigger, 3) values entered by a human when triggering manually. What will trigger the job in the lower environment?

Comment: what i mean is instead of pipeline script being embedded, its pulled from git each time.   There really isnt an option to set parameters are variables before or after the pull.  seems the code has to be written/designed to read from some properties file and we have to deploy that the relevant properties file for each environment.

Comment: Parameters are set by whatever triggers the job - think passing parameters to a function call. What would be your trigger?

Comment: these are scheduled jobs